# Python pandas creating an uneven multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code,

```
IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY = [['PATRIMONY'],['GOLD']]
IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_ASSETS = [['ASSETS'],['DEPOSITS', 'ADVANCES']]
IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_LIABILITIES = [['LIABILITIES'], ['CLIENTS', 'SUPPLIERS']]

IDX_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY)
IDX_BANKNOTER_ASSETS = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_ASSETS)
IDX_BANKNOTER_LIABILITIES = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_LIABILITIES)

IDX_BANKNOTER = IDX_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY.append(IDX_BANKNOTER_ASSETS).append(IDX_BANKNOTER_LIABILITIES)

print(IDX_BANKNOTER)
```

which prints the following index:

```
MultiIndex([(  'PATRIMONY',      'GOLD'),
            (     'ASSETS',  'DEPOSITS'),
            (     'ASSETS',  'ADVANCES'),
            ('LIABILITIES',   'CLIENTS'),
            ('LIABILITIES', 'SUPPLIERS')],
           )
```

(I used `.from_product()` because I hope to eventually add more labels)
My question is the following: I want to extend this multiindex on a third column, so that I get a multiindex that looks like:

```
'PATRIMONY', 'GOLD',
'ASSETS', 'DEPOSITS',
'ASSETS', 'ADVANCES',
'LIABILITIES', 'CLIENTS', 'Dr. Foo'
'LIABILITIES', 'CLIENTS', 'Dr. House'
'LIABILITIES', 'CLIENTS', 'Richard'
'LIABILITIES', 'SUPPLIERS', 'PORT1',
'LIABILITIES', 'SUPPLIERS', 'PORT2'
```

which would mean that the multiindex would be uneven, with a third level only used by 'LIABILITIES', and distinct indexes for CLIENTS and SUPPLIERS, according to the client name or supplier name. I have tried appending the following indexes:

```
IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION_NAMES = [['LIABILITIES'], ['CLIENTS'], ['Dr. Foo', 'Dr. House', 'Richard']]
IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION_NAMES)
IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION_NAMES = [['LIABILITIES'], ['SUPPLIERS'], ['PORT1', 'PORT2']]
IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION_NAMES)
DESIRED_RESULT = IDX_BANKNOTER.append(IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION).append(IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION)
```

but all I get in return is:

```
MultiIndex([(  'PATRIMONY',      'GOLD'),
            (     'ASSETS',  'DEPOSITS'),
            (     'ASSETS',  'ADVANCES'),
            ('LIABILITIES',   'CLIENTS'),
            ('LIABILITIES',   'CLIENTS'),
            ('LIABILITIES',   'CLIENTS'),
            ('LIABILITIES', 'SUPPLIERS'),
            ('LIABILITIES', 'SUPPLIERS')],
           )
```

I am fairly new to using pandas, and the documentation on multiindexes hasn't been helpful (it has a fairly limited number of examples for initializing multiindexes, and no example of an uneven multiindex). Does anyone have pointers? I am making this multiindex for easy manipulation of the corresponding data, being able for example to access a specific client account with

```
df['LIABILITIES']['CLIENTS']['(CLIENT NAME)']
```

or to be able to get the sum of all values under `['CLIENTS']`. I would ideally like to keep the columns of the dataframe for time labels.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Technically you can't have a MultiIndex with uneven levels, you'll be required to have *something* as the value, pandas might use `NaN` but really `NaN` in an index is problematic. If you find yourself in this situation it's probably best not to have such a MultiIndex. You should be able to have the `Client Name` as a column which would make more sense here, instead of having NaN in the MultiIndex.

Comment: @ALollz I see... I wanted to keep columns for time labels... But I will see how I can try to work around this. Thank you, I didn't know uneven multiindexes weren't possible.

Comment: Okay that's a fair use-case to want to add it to the index.

Comment: Patrimony and assest seem like a good candidate to be moved to the other axis before you add the next level...(if they are columns pass them to set_index and if they are rows pass them to reset_index(drop=False))

Comment: @RichieV thank you for your comment. If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting I move patrimony and assets to columns (or to rows if the current index is used as columns). In this case, items would be both in liabilities and either in patrimony or assets. This does make sense in accounting terms, but the issue would be how to organize the time labels.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you're doing. Would it make sense to keep two separate DataFrames for assets and liabilities? And `.merge()` when you need to see them side by side

Comment: @RichieV I think this would help data manipulation a lot. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code:

```
import pandas as pd

IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY = [['PATRIMONY'],['GOLD'], ['']]
IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_ASSETS = [['ASSETS'],['DEPOSITS', 'ADVANCES'], ['']]

IDX_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY)
IDX_BANKNOTER_ASSETS = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_VALS_BANKNOTER_ASSETS)

IDX_BANKNOTER = IDX_BANKNOTER_PATRIMONY.append(IDX_BANKNOTER_ASSETS)

IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION_NAMES = [['LIABILITIES'], ['CLIENTS'], ['Dr. Foo', 'Dr. House', 'Richard']]
IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION_NAMES)
IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION_NAMES = [['LIABILITIES'], ['SUPPLIERS'], ['PORT1', 'PORT2']]
IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION_NAMES)
WANTED_RESULT = IDX_BANKNOTER.append(IDX_FIRST_EXTENSION).append(IDX_SECOND_EXTENSION)

print(WANTED_RESULT)
```

output:

```
MultiIndex([(  'PATRIMONY',      'GOLD',          ''),
            (     'ASSETS',  'DEPOSITS',          ''),
            (     'ASSETS',  'ADVANCES',          ''),
            ('LIABILITIES',   'CLIENTS',   'Dr. Foo'),
            ('LIABILITIES',   'CLIENTS', 'Dr. House'),
            ('LIABILITIES',   'CLIENTS',   'Richard'),
            ('LIABILITIES', 'SUPPLIERS',     'PORT1'),
            ('LIABILITIES', 'SUPPLIERS',     'PORT2')],
           )
```

Comment: this does seem like the only option if multiindexes are technically impossible